# unity runtime import static object - possible way?

Tags: unity-game-engine, static, light

I was going to create an app where user can import a 3D asset, say a house, and then paint a texture over it in unity.

I then remembered that as my newbee knowledge confirms, we can only mark an object static in unity IDE before compiling, for light calculations.

I could not figure out even how to google this, to find possible answers for such a use case: how I could deal with light for such an static object?

Until now only thing comes to my mind: to earn 100k$ from my game and have payed Unity, so that to have reasonable realtime light calculations, but my newbee games will not do that.

Maybe there is another way for that or even there are already existing tutorials just teaching to make such a trivial app. If you know please give me a link or a know how.

Comment: Could you more clearly specify the problem? You have problem with light calculations because your object is static? What is a reasonable light calculations, how is unity's default not satisfying for you? And most important of all what realtime calculations of light has to do with painting textures over objects in unity?

Comment: Sorry if it is not enough clear. I will first make sure in comment with you on making my question (I've trouble in expressing it clearly in fact) and then will edit the above text eventually. I have an assumption and I'm not sure if it is correct, I express it like this: "It is not possible to import an FBX model in runtime, by user, and have unity (free edition) render light for it when user is painting it". Please let me know if this is correct or I miss any fundamental concept here. Thank you.

Comment: I believe its possible to update the material's texture, so you would have to get a point from 3D object in runtime (that was clicked or selected) calculate what point corresponds to it in texture and change it, basically reverse engineering what a shader does, but thats overly complicated, and unneccessary, the easier approach is to use tesselation shaders.

Comment: So you confirm that my assumption is right and we must write code that is responsible to calculate a light map in run time, i.e. we can not use any unity API right out of the box for this use case?

Comment: Light map has nothing to do with your problem, and yes there is no ready to use methods in unity api for this but I would try to search in asset store first.

Comment: Thank you, meanwhile I found some new resources too, I'd study them then update this question and maybe provide answer myself, maybe useful for someone else.